# Not able to do sudo apt-get update after installing Mongo DB

Tags: linux-mint, mongodb

I tried installing MongoDb on my linux mint Rosa 17.3 system from the following link

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

However when I type and run sudo apt-get update, it throws the following error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/rosa/mongodb- 
org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/rosa/mongodb-
org/3.0/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old 
ones used instead.
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with the url you are using.

http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/

has precise and trusty under it, as you can check. It does not have rosa. The guide you link to also only mentions precise and trusty. You seem to have assumed
it would have packages for Mint releases, which is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: That aside: Mint in general is not Ubuntu.

Comment: @Fiximan corrected.